# req.body returns empty object

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm trying to create an API that creates a new product in Expressjs and Mongoose.
Once I send the request with full body, I get the body as empty object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyrNn.png)

and here is a screenshot from the postman :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFFj6.png)

Comment: Are you using the express.json() middleware?

Comment: Always prefer to add code as <code> not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a parser middleware (like `ajv`) which first validates the request body sent and then, if it's valid, proceeds to the logic of your endpoint. As seen in your image of Postman, the error says that you lack some necessary information. Have you made some request body schemas? If you have, you can add it on your post so that we can debug it further.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the bundled express.json() middleware but still getting the same issue

Comment: @CaptainAlpha did you set your header content-type to `application/json` ?

Comment: No, why would I? because I'm not just sending json, but also files